# Python: Updating a CSV file in place

Tags: python, csv

Is there a sensible way to update CSV data, in the same file, one row at a time?

I have a CSV of records to inspect and potentially fix, a one-off task I am solving with an ad-hoc script. The script will require iteration to make it work correctly. It will categorise each record, decide on an action, attempt that action and record the result. I want to append these stages to the CSV:

```
id,status,action,result
123
234
345
456
```

to

```
id,status,action,result
123,OK,None
234,INVALID,Fix,OK
345,INVALID,Fix
456
```

Oh no, my script crashed while trying to fix 345 due to a bug! So I'll fix the bug and run the script again, and it will skip the rows where `status:OK` or `result:OK`:

```
id,status,action,result
123,OK,None
234,INVALID,Fix,OK
345,INVALID,Fix,OK
456,OK,None
```

Is this possible?

One approach is to load the CSV into memory then overwrite the original file:

```py
fieldnames = "id status action result".split()
data = []

def process_and_update(record):
    if record["status"] != "OK":
        ...


with open("file.csv", "r", newline="") as input_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    next(reader) # skip header row
    for r in reader:
        data.append(r)

with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for record in data:
        process_and_update(record)
        writer.writerow(record)
```

This doesn't work because if `process_and_update(record)` throws an unexpected error then the remaining data is lost.

The method I'm currently using is to write to a separate file:

```
with open("file1.csv", "r", newline="") as input_file, \
     open("file2.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:
     
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    next(reader)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for record in reader:
        record.update(process_and_update(record))
        writer.writerow(record)
```

But this requires action to give the script correct filenames each time. If I keep using the original file as input, it will do the status-checking over and over again, which is slow.

Or should I just put the data into an sqlite file?

Answer (score 0):

Found another partial answer, but it will corrupt the file if there's an unhandled error:

```
with open(filename, "r", newline="") as input_file, \
    open(filename, "r+", newline="") as output_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for record in reader:
        print(f"{record['id']}... ", end="")
        
        if record["id"] == "345":
            print("Fail")
            raise Exception("simulated crash")
        
        else:
            print("OK")
            record["result"] = "OK"
            
        writer.writerow(record)
```

At the point when the `with output_file` context ends, `DictWriter` gets written to the file. If it ends due to an unhandled exception, the original file gets partially overwritten:

```
id,status,action,result
123,
234,
345,
456,
567,
678,
789,
890,
```

to

```
id,status,action,result
123,,,OK
234,,,OK
6,        <--- "345,\n456," overwritten
567,
678,
789,
890,
```

So… this solution works if you're confident you'll never crash. Otherwise it's probably best to have a separate input file and output file.